# How to assign to ManytoMany None object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a task to modify queryset after that a recieved its from DB and before context.
I do the next:

```
products = list(qs) #create a copy of qs to avoid modifiyng in DB
for product in products:
    access_table = FieldAccess.objects.filter(user=user, product=product.pk).values_list('access', flat=True)
    fields = [Choices.objects.filter(pk=item).values_list('field_name', flat=True) for item in access_table
              if not access_table[0] == None]
    for field in fields:
        setattr(product, field[0], None)  #assign a new value to particular field of object
return products
```

It works fine except of ManyToMany Fields. If i try to set None value I get an error:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What do I have to assign?

**Prehistory**
I need to limit value visibility of particular field items in the model for particular users.
I created intermediate model that contain references on user,object of model and wich fields should be hiden. I realy don't no how to implement that via queryset, but my snippet with modifiyng on the fly works well

Comment: what ever it is that you are trying to do querying the database in a loop probably isn't the right approach. if you could explain in detail what your objective is ...

Answer (score -1):

The way to reset a `ManyToManyField` field is to use `clear`.  [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
value = getattr(product, fields[0], None)
if value and isinstance(value, ManyToManyField): value.clear()
```

Comment: This actually modifies the DB, which is not what the author intended. See the first comment in the code.

Answer (score -1):

ManyToManyFields perform some magic under the hood. You cannot simply assign `None`, because it expects an Iterable. You would have to assign an empty list `[]` to ManyToManyFields instead, but this actually performs a database query and is probably not what you want!

You could try to workaround that, but I would simply build a dictionary of the information you actually want to pass to the template.

```
products = []
for product in qs:
    access_table = FieldAccess.objects.filter(user=user, product=product.pk).values_list('access', flat=True)
    fields = [Choices.objects.filter(pk=item).values_list('field_name', flat=True) for item in access_table
              if not access_table[0] == None]
    products.append({field[0]: None for field in fields})
return products
```

Comment: That being said, it is really not obvious what you are actually trying to achieve, but as @e4c5 commented, your approach seem questionable. Maybe you can expand your question with more context and we can find a better solution.

Comment: You don’t ever iterate over the ManyToManyField itself.  You iterate over the `.all` or the `.filter` call on the relationship field.

Comment: It looks like we both got this wrong.  At least for v1.9, assigning `[]` is equivalent to `clear`.

Comment: @ps you are right on both accounts. I'll update my answer now